# How do you do the Partial Fraction expansion of $\dfrac{1}{x(M-x)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you do the Partial Fraction expansion of $\dfrac{1}{x(M-x)}$?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{M-x}$ is almost right.

Comment: Can you do $\frac1{x(2-x)}$ and $\frac1{x(3-x)}$?  If so, the $M$ should not cause any problems - it's just a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the common denominator:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{x(M-x)}
&=\frac{A}x
+\frac{B}{M-x} \\
&=\frac{A}x\cdot\frac{M-x}{M-x}
+\frac{x}{x}\cdot\frac{B}{M-x}.
\end{align}
$$
Then, equating the numerators,
or multiplying through by the
common denominator $x(M-x)$,
we get
$$
\begin{align}
1&=A(M-x)+Bx \\
 &=(B-A)x+(AM).
\end{align}
$$
These two steps are often combined and called "cross multiplying".

Since this is a polynomial equation,
we can equate the coefficients of $x$
and of the constant terms, leading to
two equations in the two unknowns $A$ & $B$:
$$ B-A=0,\quad AM=1 $$
so that A=B=1/M:
$$\frac1{x(M-x)}=\frac1M\left(\frac1x+\frac1{M-x}\right).$$

Comment: +1 for detailed answer. Though you could have left it at the first step leaving the rest to @Artas.

Comment: I like this answer because of how detailed it is. 

It took me an hour trying to understand why there was another 1/M but thanks to you I finally understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That will be $\dfrac{1}{Mx} + \dfrac{1}{M(M-x)}$